# declval<_Xp(&)()>()() - what does this mean in the below context?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits

This is from: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits

```
  template<typename _Xp, typename _Yp>
    using __cond_res
      = decltype(false ? declval<_Xp(&)()>()() : declval<_Yp(&)()>()());
...
  template<typename _Tp1, typename _Tp2>
    struct __common_reference_impl<_Tp1, _Tp2, 3,
                   void_t<__cond_res<_Tp1, _Tp2>>>
    { using type = __cond_res<_Tp1, _Tp2>; };
```

I'm trying to figure out what `_Xp(&)()` is - is it a function call signature? i.e. a constructor? Doesn't really make sense. It seems there is a anonymous variable name there, i.e.:

```
_Xp(&anon)()
```

I still can't wrap my head around it somehow and I've been coding C++ for the last 34 years.

Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would interpret it as function type declarations, where `_Xp` and `_Yp` are template type parameters, the ampersands indicate that they are references to functions of the type `_Xp` or `_Yp`, and `()` means that they have no input arguments.

Comment: It's a type: a reference to a function that takes no parameters and returns an `_Xp`.

Comment: Pretty similar to the type of a function pointer `_Xp(*)()`; just using a reference, not a pointer...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik (and all): My thought is that this is syntactic sugar to generate whatever C++ value category is represented by a method returning by value an _Xp. As a side question: What value category is a C++ return-by-value? It's not an rvalue-reference and I looked at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category and I couldn't easily figure it out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

tl;dr; We need a way to produce an expression with type and value category `T`, not type and value category `T&&`, so we can't just use `std::declval<T>()` and instead need to do something else.

---

The point of this:

```cpp
  template<typename _Xp, typename _Yp>
    using __cond_res
      = decltype(false ? declval<_Xp(&)()>()() : declval<_Yp(&)()>()());
```

is to give you the type of `false ? x : y` where `x` is an expression of type and value category `_Xp` and `y` is an expression of type and value category `_Yp`.

The conditional operator (usually called the ternary operator), `?:`, is an extremely complicated language feature. It's one of the places in the language where there is actually a differentiation between prvalues and xvalues.

The naive way to implement this would be:

```cpp
  template<typename _Xp, typename _Yp>
    using __cond_res
      = decltype(false ? declval<_Xp>() : declval<_Yp>());
```

Because, well, isn't that what `declval<T>()` is for, to give you a `T`? But actually, there's a flaw here, because `declval` isn't specified as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto declval() -> T;
```

It's specified as (`add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` rather than `T&&` to correctly handle `void`):

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto declval() -> std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>;
```

As a result, `__cond_res<int, int>` and `__cond_res<int&&, int&&>` would be indistinguishable, even though the first needs to be `int` while the latter needs to be `int&&`.

---

So, we need a way to actually produce an arbitrary expression of type `T`. One way would to just actually:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto better_declval() -> T;

template<typename _Xp, typename _Yp>
  using __cond_res
    = decltype(false ? better_declval<_Xp>() : better_declval<_Yp>());
```

This works.

An alternative is to produce an instance of a function that gives you `T` and then invoke it. That's what `declval<_Xp(&)()>()()` does - gives you a reference to a nullary function that returns a `_Xp`, and then invokes it, giving you an `_Xp` (of the correct value category).

In this case, this seems like unnecessary complexity compared to the `better_declval` approach, but it turns out that this pattern is useful in other contexts as well. Like concepts:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept something = requires (T(&obj)()){
    f(obj());
};
```

Here, I have a concept that checks to see if I can call `f` with an expression of type `T`, including differentiating between prvalues and xvalues correctly. The above is the most convenient way I know of to achieve that goal. Which is, admittedly, unfortunate.

You could also do:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept something = requires {
    f(better_declval<T>());
};
```

It just depends on your perspective I guess, and how many times you need to use `obj`.

Once you've seen this `T(&)()` pattern used in the concept context, it's a familiar pattern, so it makes sense to just use it consistently.

Comment: Asking this question again: What value category is a C++ return-by-value? I couldn't easily figure it out by looking at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @DavidBien Like given `int foo();`, what is the value category of `foo()`? It's a prvalue.

Answer (score 12):

> declval<_Xp(&)()>()() - what does this mean

`_Xp(&)()` is a reference to a function that takes no parameters.

`declval<_Xp(&)()>()` (meaning `std::decvlval`) is a hypothetical instance of this function.

`declval<_Xp(&)()>()()` is calling that hypothetical instance, producing a return value.

Collectively, it means "The value that would be returned by calling a function of type `_Xp`."

Comment: *"The value that would be returned by calling a function of type `_Xp`."* I think you mean of type `_Xp()`?

Answer (score 9):

- `_Xp(&)()` is a reference to a function taking no parameters and returning `_Xp`.
- `declval<_Xp(&)()>()()` returns such a function reference and invokes it, which results in `_Xp`.

```cpp
decltype(false ? declval<_Xp(&)()>()() : declval<_Yp(&)()>()())
```

... is a common type of `_Xp` and `_Yp`, following the rules of the conditional operator.

The difference to just using `declval<_Xp>()` is that `declval` doesn't return a value, it returns `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<_Xp>`.

You can see that this type alias is being used to determine the common reference between two types:

```cpp
template<typename _Tp1, typename _Tp2>
struct __common_reference_impl<_Tp1, _Tp2, 3, void_t<__cond_res<_Tp1, _Tp2>>>
{ using type = __cond_res<_Tp1, _Tp2>; };
```

---

*Note: you can use [cdecl+](https://cdecl.plus/?decl=int(%26)()) to better understand C and C++ type syntax.*

Comment: `declval<_Xp>()` (if `_Xp` isn't void) will never be a prvalue, always an xvalue or lvalue, so your simplified version would add a lot of rvalue references when it should just be values. Also this checks for arrays/functions that can't be the return type of a function (e.g., `common_reference<int[3], int[3]>` is `int*`, not `int(&)[3]` or `int(&&)[3]`, and `common_reference<int(), int()>` is `int(*)()`, not `int(&)()`)

Comment: @Artyer As I commented above:  My thought is that this is syntactic sugar to generate whatever C++ value category is represented by a method returning by value an _Xp. As a side question: What value category is a C++ return-by-value? It's not an rvalue-reference and I looked at en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category and I couldn't easily figure it out.

Comment: @DavidBien when a function returns a value, calling it is a prvalue expression. Returning references produces lvalues or xvalues depending on the kind of reference.

Comment: @JanSchultke thanks - it's first explanation under prvalue in cppref - I read it and somehow it didn't grok but now it does.